# how to get a value to change with an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue where I am trying to change a value based on what is clicked in my form. As you can see in the images below:

here is what the form looks like when the page is first loaded.
[image]

when I click on the custom input box it changes the color which is good
[image]

and when I click on the other buttons it toggles the background color which is good.

[image]

but then when I click anywhere on the screen besides the buttons the background color remains. If there isn't a value inputted in the box and the user clicks anywhere on the screen I want the value to automatically return the the default of 50
[image]

here is my jquery:

```
var defaultValue = 50; 

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#donation-amount').keyup(function() {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');

      if($(this).val()) {
         $('#display-amount').text($(this).val());
    } else {
       $('#display-amount').text(defaultValue);
       $("#default").addClass('active');
       $("#btn2").removeClass('active');
       $("#btn3").removeClass('active');
    }
});

     $( ".selectvalue" ).click(function() {
        $('#display-amount').text($(this).val());
     });

    $(".buttons .btn").click(function(){
        $(".buttons .btn").removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
      $('#donation-amount').css("background-color","") 
    });
$("#donation-amount").click(function() {

         if ($(this).hasClass('inpt-first')) {
             $(this).css("background-color", "#c97e06");
             // $('#donation-amount').text('--');
             $("#default").removeClass('active');
             $("#btn2").removeClass('active');
             $("#btn3").removeClass('active');
            $('#display-amount').text('--');
         } 

        else{
            $(this).css("background-color","") 
            $("#default").addClass('active');   
            $(this).removeClass('inpt-first');

        }

    });

    $('#display-amount').text($('#default').val());

});
```

and here is my html:

```
<div class="form-container">
<div class="donate-heading text-center">
  <h1>Donate Now!</h1>
</div>
<div class="form-content">

<form action="" method="POST" id="payment-form">
  <span class="payment-errors"></span>

  <div class="content-inner">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <fieldset>
        <legend class="text-center">How much would you like to donate</legend>
        <div class="choose-pricing">
          <div class="btn-group">
          <div class="buttons">
            <button type="button" id="default" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color active" value="50">50</button>
            <button type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color" value="100">100</button>
            <button type="button" id="btn3" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color" value="150">150</button>
            <input type="Custom" name="donation-amount" class="inpt-first form-control" id="donation-amount" onclick="if(this.defaultValue == this.value) this.value = ''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" value="Custom">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="donation-amount-value" id="donation-amount-value">
          </div>
          <div class="money-donate">
            <div class="display-amount" id="display-amount">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
  <legend class="text-center">Enter your card details</legend>
  <span class="full">Enter yor 16 digit card number:</span>
  <div class="credit-card-num">
    <input type="text" name="cardNumber" id="creditCardNumber" onclick="if(this.defaultValue == this.value) this.value = ''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" value="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX" data-stripe="number">
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
  <div class="date-wrapper">
    <div class="month">
      <span class="full">Month & Year of Expiry:</span>
      <select name="month" id="expMonth" class="selectBox chzn-done" data-stripe="exp-month">
        <option data-stripe="cvc">Select Month</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
      <div id="expMonth_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1">
        </a>
      </div>
      <select name="year" id="expYear" class="selectBox chzn-done" data-stripe="exp-year">
        <option value="">Select Year</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="cvn">
      <span class="full">Card Verrification Number
        <a href="#" class="tooltip">
          <img src="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/question.png" alt="question">
        </a>
        <div class="tooltip-hover">
          <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
      </span>
      <input type="password" name="cardVeriNum" id="cardVeriNum">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <fieldset class="personal-detail">
    <legend class="text-center">Personal Details</legend>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
       <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <textarea name="address" class="form-control" id="address">Address</textarea> -->
        <textarea name="notes" class="form-control" id="add-note" placeholder="Additional Notes"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group button">
      <div class="text-center">
      <button id="donate-btn" value="Donate" class="btn btn-default">Donate</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harishkommuri/tb6kpr21/3/).

Add following script to your script.

```
$('#donation-amount').blur(function() {
  $(this).attr('style', '');
  if($(this).val() == null || $(this).val() == 'Custom') {
    $('button.selectvalue:first-child').addClass('active');
    $('#display-amount').text(50);
  }
});
```

Comment: Making progress! So when I click elsewhere on the page the background color is gone but unfortunately 50 isn't showing up in display-amount and the background color isn't returning the default button

Comment: Yes!! The background color switched to the default but I'm not sure why 50 isn't showing up in #display-amount. It's not automatically switching back to display 50.

Comment: I don't think `Custom` is the value of input. I think it is a placeholder. Now the code is changed Try it.

Comment: I did get it to work! I removed the if statement and everything is fine! Thanks for the help!